# Parse String as HTML in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-parsing

So, I have a textarea that users are supposed to type codes into.

Ex: `<div id="example">blar</div>`

How can I evaluate what they enter in the textarea as HTML (as in the DOM) without:

- jQuery
- Having to create a new element

For example:

Code: `<div id="ex">Blar</div>`

My Function:

```
function parseCode(){
    var code = document.getElementById("code").value;
}
```

I want to take the value and make it accessible (like `code.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML`);

Comment: Why the arbitrary-seeming restriction of not creating a new element?

Comment: Well, I guess I can create one, kinda with what Chris was saying.

Isn't there something like document.evalute?

Comment: The `innerHTML` property is about a good as it gets; you just need a parent element to use.  When you set an element's `innerHTML` property to an HTML string, the string gets parsed and the element gets populated with the result.

Comment: @RickyAYoder  :you can try the solution I gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var ele = document.createElement('div');
ele.innerHTML = document.getElementById('code').value;
```

This does not create a new element on the page itself, only in memory

Comment: And if I assigned it a className/id, I could access it and each of the children as what the user typed as their code, no?

Comment: Yes, the html is evaluated when you assign it to the container's innerHTML property. All of the nodes defined in the user submitted HTML become actual child nodes of the newly created div, again, all in memory.

Comment: Nice! concise. I didn't think of it :P